# How to make a single image using several images?

Tags: python, opencv

I have these images and there is a shadow in all images. I target is making a single image of a car without shadow by using these three images:

[image]

Finally, how can I get this kind of image as shown below:

[image]

Any kind of help or suggestions are appreciated.

**EDITED**

According to the comments, I used `np.maximum` and achieved easily to my target:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_1 = cv2.imread('1.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_2 = cv2.imread('2.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img = np.maximum(img_1, img_2)

cv2.imshow('img1', img_1)
cv2.imshow('img2', img_2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Do you already know where the shadows in each image is?

Comment: Nope, I do not know.

Comment: Solution specific to the above image: If you check all the pixels in the first row (x coordinate = 0) whether they exactly match white or not you can determine where the gray boxes are and once you know where the boxes are the process is quite simple then.

Comment: does what you mean work for if the shadow has different shapes? I make it rectangular for the simplicity of exmplanation of my question.

Comment: Let me see if I understood your question correctly. You have three images of cars with a "shadow" (the grey rectangle) on them. You need to cut the shadow out of all three images and join them to create a composite image, free of the shadow. Is that right?

Comment: @stateMachine, yes, right.

Comment: Just take the maximum value each pixel between each image. Max(image1, image2, image3) for each pixel. You can do that with Numpy for example using np.max(image1,np.max(image2,image3)) See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html. The images must be previously aligned to match in scale and orientation and position and shape.

Comment: @fmw42, thank you so much, your advice worked perfectly for me and I posted it as an answer below. Thank you.

Comment: instead of the (per-pixel) maximum, consider the median or mode. also consider *trying* to solve your problem before asking. you didn't post any code, which is a good indication that you don't have code from any attempts.

Comment: If maximum doesnt work, and you know that for each position there are more images without the shadow/corruption: Use the median of all images.

Comment: @Micka, maximum worked well for me, I posted below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. The overall idea is to compute the location of the shadows, produce a binary mask identifying the location of the shadows and use this information to copy pixels from all the cropped sub-images.

Let's see the code. The first problem is to locate the three images. I used the black box to segment and crop each car, like this:

```
# Imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "qRLI7.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Get the HSV image:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get the grayscale image:
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
showImage("grayImage", grayImage)

# Threshold via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow("binaryImage", binaryImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The previous bit uses the `grayscale` version of the image and applies a fixed binarization using a threshold of `5`. I also pre-compute the `HSV` version of the original image. The result of the thresholding is this:

[image]

I'm trying to get the black rectangles and use them to crop each car. Let's get the contours and filter them by area, as the black rectangles on the binary image have the biggest area:

```
for i, c in enumerate(currentContour):

    # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Get the area:
    blobArea = rectWidth * rectHeight
    minArea = 20000

    if blobArea > minArea:

        # Deep local copies:
        hsvImage = hsvImage.copy()
        localImage = inputImage.copy()

        # Get the S channel from the HSV image:
        (H, S, V) = cv2.split(hsvImage)

        # Crop image:
        croppedImage = V[rectY:rectY + rectHeight, rectX:rectX + rectWidth]
        localImage = localImage[rectY:rectY + rectHeight, rectX:rectX + rectWidth]

        _, binaryMask = cv2.threshold(croppedImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

After filtering each contour to get the biggest one, I need to locate the position of the shadow. The shadow is mostly visible in the `HSV` color space, particularly, in the `V` channel. I cropped two versions of the image: The original `BGR` image, now cropped, and the `V` cropped channel of the `HSV` image. This is the binary mask that results from applying an automatic thresholding on the `S` channel :

[image]

To locate the shadow I only need the starting `x` coordinate and its `width`, because the shadow is uniform across every cropped image. Its `height` is equal to each cropped image's height. I reduced the `V` image to a row, using the `SUM` mode. This will sum each pixel across all columns. The biggest values will correspond to the position of the shadow:

```
        # Image reduction:
        reducedImg = cv2.reduce(binaryMask, 0, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32S)
    
        # Normalize image:
        max = np.max(reducedImg)
        reducedImg = reducedImg / max

        # Clip the values to [0,255]
        reducedImg = np.clip((255 * reducedImg), 0, 255)

        # Convert the mat type from float to uint8:
        reducedImg = reducedImg.astype("uint8")

        _, shadowMask = cv2.threshold(reducedImg, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

The reduced image is just a row:

[image]

The white pixels denote the largest values. The location of the shadow is drawn like a horizontal line with the largest area, that is, the most contiguous white pixels. I process this row by getting contours and filtering, again, to the largest area:

```
        # Get the biggest rectangle:
        subContour, _ = cv2.findContours(shadowMask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for j, s in enumerate(subContour):

            # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
            boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(s)

            # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
            rectX = boundRect[0]
            rectY = boundRect[1]
            rectWidth = boundRect[2]
            rectHeight = boundRect[3]

            # Get the area:
            blobArea = rectWidth * rectHeight
            minArea = 30

            if blobArea > minArea:

                # Get image dimensions:
                (imageHeight, imageWidth) = localImage.shape[:2]

                # Set an empty array, this will be the binary mask
                shadowMask = np.zeros((imageHeight, imageWidth, 3), np.uint8)
                color = (255, 255, 255)
                cv2.rectangle(shadowMask, (int(rectX), int(0)),
                          (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(0 + imageHeight)), color, -1)
                # Invert mask:
                shadowMask = 255 - shadowMask

                # Store mask and cropped image:
                shadowRois.append((shadowMask.copy(), localImage.copy()))
```

Alright, with that information I create a mask, where the only thing drawn in white is the location of the mask. I store this mask and the original `BGR` crop in the `shadowRois` list.

What follows is a possible method to use this information and create a full image. The idea is that I use the information of each mask to copy all the non-masked pixels. I accumulate this information on a buffer, initially an empty image, like this:

```
# Prepare image buffer:
buffer = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), np.uint8)

# Loop through cropped images and produce the final image:
for r in range(len(shadowRois)):

    # Get data from the list:
    (mask, img) = shadowRois[r]
    # Get image dimensions:
    (imageHeight, imageWidth) = img.shape[:2]

    # Resize the buffer:
    newSize = (imageWidth, imageHeight)
    buffer = cv2.resize(buffer, newSize, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # Get the image mask:
    temp = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

    # Set info in buffer, substitute the black pixels
    # for the new data:
    buffer = np.where(temp == (0, 0, 0), buffer, temp)

    cv2.imshow("Composite Image", buffer)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: This answer is also incredible and I really appreciate it. Thank you so much @stateMachine.

Comment: I decided to choose your answer as a correct answer to this question because of your efforts. But the approach fmw42 suggested is really good for me. Thank you @stateMachine.